# Mismatch version between installed package and executable version printing

Tags: php, php-fpm, apt, package-management

I am facing an issue about mismatch between last updated package of PHP and what is actually run.

Recently I have updated my Ubuntu server by running:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

On the output I have noticed the right package version was installed:

```
Unpacking php7.1-fpm (7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (PHP Version 7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
```

I have controlled the installed version by running following command:

```
apt-cache madison php7.1-fpm
php7.1-fpm | 7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

But when I run `phpinfo()` from php-fpm socket, I still see the previous installed version:

```
PHP Version 7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

**What I have tried?**

- To restart `php7.1-fpm`.
- To restart Nginx (which is in top of PHP fpm).

---

**EDIT 1**

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php

$ ls -al /usr/bin | grep php
php -> /etc/alternatives/php
php7.1

$ ls -al /etc/alternatives | grep php 
php -> /usr/bin/php7.1
php.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php7.1.1.gz

$ /usr/bin/php7.1 -v
PHP 7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 08:15:52) ( NTS )
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```
$ dpkg -l 'php*'|grep ^ii
ii  php-common         2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3   all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php-geoip          1.1.1-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+10      amd64        GeoIP module for PHP
ii  php-igbinary       3.0.1+2.0.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        igbinary PHP serializer
ii  php-memcached      3.1.3+2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        memcached extension module for PHP, uses libmemcached
ii  php-msgpack        2.0.3+0.5.7-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        PHP extension for interfacing with MessagePack
ii  php-redis          5.0.2+4.3.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        PHP extension for interfacing with Redis
ii  php7.1             7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.1-cli         7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.1-common      7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.1-curl        7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-fpm         7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.1-gd          7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.1-gmp         7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        GMP module for PHP
ii  php7.1-intl        7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.1-json        7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mbstring    7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mcrypt      7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mysql       7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-opcache     7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.1-readline    7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.1-sqlite3     7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        SQLite3 module for PHP
ii  php7.1-xml         7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-zip         7.1.25-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zip module for PHP
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `which php`?

Comment: i have updated my post, it is for `php cli` which have the same original issue than `php7.1-fpm`

Comment: Could you please show the output of `dpkg -l 'php*'|grep ^ii` ?

Comment: I have updated my post, i have may find someting.

Comment: @jollyroger thx for your help, after forcing upgrade of all sub package, all was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of installed packages shows only `php7.1` to be of version 7.1.33 but all subpackages aren't upgraded to the 7.1.33. You might want to upgrade `php7.1-cli` and `php7.1-fpm` to upgrade all dependant packages at once as they have more strict version dependency.

You might want to use `apt-cache policy` in future since `apt-cache madison` shows available packages and not installed on a system:

```
[jollyroger@desktop:~]% apt-cache policy vim-tiny
vim-tiny:
  Installed: 2:8.1.0875-5+b1
  Candidate: 2:8.1.2136-1
  Version table:
     2:8.1.2136-1 990
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:8.1.0875-5+b1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:8.1.0875-5 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

Please note the *Installed* line as well as the line marked with `***`.

Comment: What is confusing for me is why simple `apt-get upgrade` doesn't update all my previously installed package ? on my case i was forcing to do `apt-get upgrade php7.1-cli`

Comment: This is because `php7.1` depends on `(libapache2-mod-php7.1 | php7.1-cgi | php7.1-fpm)` with no exact version specified (e.g. `(php7.1-fpm = 7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)`) and thus the dependency relies on the package name only. This is most probably not intended behavior and bug should be filed to Debian/Ubuntu BTS.

Answer (score 0):

base on the recommandation from @jollyroger in comment, i have force `apt-get` to upgrade all sub package for PHP.

```
apt-get upgrade php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-curl php7.1-fpm php7.1-gd php7.1-gmp php7.1-intl php7.1-json php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mysql php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline php7.1-sqlite3 php7.1-xml php7.1-zip
```

Then all package was updated like charm :

```
$ dpkg -l 'php*'|grep ^ii
ii  php-common         2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3   all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php-geoip          1.1.1-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+10      amd64        GeoIP module for PHP
ii  php-igbinary       3.0.1+2.0.8-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        igbinary PHP serializer
ii  php-memcached      3.1.3+2.2.0-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        memcached extension module for PHP, uses libmemcached
ii  php-msgpack        2.0.3+0.5.7-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        PHP extension for interfacing with MessagePack
ii  php-redis          5.0.2+4.3.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64        PHP extension for interfacing with Redis
ii  php7.1             7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.1-cli         7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.1-common      7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.1-curl        7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-fpm         7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.1-gd          7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.1-gmp         7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        GMP module for PHP
ii  php7.1-intl        7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
ii  php7.1-json        7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mbstring    7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mcrypt      7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mysql       7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-opcache     7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.1-readline    7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.1-sqlite3     7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        SQLite3 module for PHP
ii  php7.1-xml         7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php7.1-zip         7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        Zip module for PHP

$ php -v
PHP 7.1.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2019 19:29:18) ( NTS )
```